# What are the available options for Eloquent's Model::save() method?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Eloquent has a method called `save()`, which takes an optional array of parameters (options).  However, the [API reference](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save) doesn't seem to explain what these options are.

Is there a list somewhere that I'm missing?  I could track them down through the source code of course (I see `touch` and `timestamp`, at least), but I figured at the very least this question would be useful as a reference to others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## tl;dr

In the `$options` array you can disable timestamping for that specific query:

```php
$item->save([
    'timestamps' => false, // Disable timestamping on insert and update.
    'touch'      => false, // Disable parent timestamping.
]);
```

> **See:** [Eloquent Model Conventions: Timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) and [Touching Parent Timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps).
> **Note:** Since 5.3 the `timestamps` option is no longer supported.

## Full review

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1430) you can see, that in the `save()` method, the `$options` variable is passed to three functions:

- `timestamps` support is provided by `performInsert()` and `performUpdate()`.
- `touch` support is provided by `finishSave()`.

### The `timestamps` option

Both `performInsert()` and `performUpdate()` will check the `timestamps` key in the `$options` array in [conjuction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) with the `$timestamps` property of the model:

```php
if ($this->timestamps && Arr::get($options, 'timestamps', true))
```

If this expression is true, it will touch the timestamps.

Because of the fact that `$option['timestamps']` defaults to true and it is in conjuction with the model property, the only use of this option (when it makes a difference) is when timestamping is enabled in the model but you want to disable it on a particular query. You can't do the opposite: enable timestamping while it is disabled in the model - which might be counterintuitive.

> **Note:** Since [5.3](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1449) the `performInsert()` and `performUpdate()` functions doesn't work with the values in the `$options` parameter.

### The `touch` option

If this option is set to false, it will disable the [touch of the parent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps) set in the model's `$touches` property. This option defaults to true so just like the `timestamps` option it is only for disabling timestamping for that particular query.

Comment: I might be a bit lost here, but the code you linked for 5.3 doesn't mention the `timestamps` option on `performUpdate()`. It seems the only option left there is `touch`, used by `finishSave()`. That holds true up to [5.7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L628).

Comment: @igorsantos07 You are right! [It got reverted](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/c31a9c5807f001f77a25bf7595a7d8e9b84faaf4) after this answer was written.